# Powering Infrared and Sonar sensors using BEC

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors

I'm new to Arduino. I'm using Arduino Mega 2560 board & MATLAB Simulink-Arduino support package and trying to integrate Maxbotix Sonar and Sharp IR sensor for my class project. When I powered single US sensor from Arduino 5V output, the readings are fine. However, when I tried to power IR sensor in parallel with US sensor, IR readings are fine but US readings fluctuate.

So, I tried powering the sensors using BEC (5V-3A). The readings for both sensors are fluctuating(extremely noisy). From the specification mentioned by manufacturers, Maxbotix US sensor draws 2mA of current, whereas IR sensor averagely draws 20mA. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the problem. When external power supply is used to power multiple sensors, connect the GND of that supply with that of the Arduino GND input. For more details, refer to the link below.

http://www.thebox.myzen.co.uk/Tutorial/Power_Supplies.html